# Two services sharing the same parent route in aws API gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I have three services which all share the same API gateway. I'm trying to get the third service to add a child route that was created from the other two services.

The two services are order and user
The user service creates /users/{user_id}
The order service creates /orders/{order_id}

The third service is history which wants to create /users/{user_id}/history and /orders/{order_id}/history

Can this be accomplished using serverless?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the https://github.com/mikesouza/serverless-import-apigateway

from what you describe might help you with your use case

Comment: Just what I needed. Just a note that if you're following the example here https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-shared-gateway then you need to remove apiGateway section under provider. The two will conflict with each other